# Paperclip - Can't get to any uploaded image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, file-upload, paperclip

I've managed to make paperclip work and upload my images, but for an unknown reason, Rails can't find them even if I can.
I'm using Windows 10 + Rubymine 2016.1, and in the arborescence's project, I can see several folders that have been colored in red by Rubymine. Those folders contain my uploaded image, but when I try to reach them through my browser or by doing `<%= image_tag(@post.image.url(:small)) %>`, I get a 404 status

[image: Folder's visual]

Here is my model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of(:titre, :contenu)
  has_attached_file :image, :styles => {
      :large => "400x400>",
      :medium => "300x300>",
      :thumb => "100x100#"
  },
  :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachment/:style/:filename",
  :url => '/images/:class/:id/:basename.:extension'
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Does anybody know what the color means, or how to fix my 404 error status ?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

While trying some vains things, I added manually the following in brut HTML :

`<img src="/system/posts/images/large/sorry.jpg" alt="">` and my image appeared just fine. So i guess the path created by @post.image.url is wrong since it's `/system/posts/images/000/000/012/medium/nope.jpg`
How can i put that in my model ?

Comment: did you try to access `image_tag(@post.image.url(:medium))`

Comment: for accessing small you have to define in model

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm stupid, but I tried then with medium and thumb, but the result was the same

Comment: what path it shows in image src?

Comment: this : `<img src="/images/posts/10/burn_heal.jpg?1460548553" alt="Burn heal" />`

Comment: can you access image via browser URL?

Comment: No, even though it exists in my explorer, and it appears in my IDE, I have no idea why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `:small` identifier declared for images. Try :

```
<%= image_tag(@post.image.url(:thumb)) %>

:path => "#{Rails.root}/public/system/:class/:attachment/:style/:filename"
```

Plus i don't think there is any need to add `:url` in the model atatchment config.

Working Fine for me like :

```
has_attached_file :image,
     :styles => {
            :thumb => "100x100#",
            :small => "300x300>",
            :large => "700x700>"
            },                                             
            :path => "image/:class/:style/:id.:extension"
```

Comment: I tried your solution, it doesn't work, even though I have this in my html : `<img src="/images/posts/10/burn_heal.jpg?1460548553" alt="Burn heal" />`

Comment: remove `:url` attribute from model

Comment: ya @Jaeger try to remove url

Comment: The :url was to avoid any file to have a too long path (and useless) path, anyway I deleted it, but still nothing

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli Thanks for your answer, I figured it out by myself, my solution is close to yours but both works, thank you all for your answers!